# Time Machine could not delete the backup disk image...!!!

Tags: time-machine, backup

I have a GoFlex Home external drive that has worked well for a long time. Every once in a while I have to change settings, but can always fix it. This latest problem has been going on for weeks. I keep getting the message that my Time Machine backup failed and that it needs to create a new backup. I click OK and that fails. I finally looked into the problem today and found advice on another site that I should change my passwords. I did that and it appeared that the new backup would start. Then I got this message: "Time Machine could not delete the backup disk image."  I can access the GoFlex drive preferences online and wipe all existing backups, but that doesn't fix the problem.

I clicked "Get Info" on the sparsebundle file and it is locked. I can unlock it, but it won't stay unlocked. Before I check into a mental hospital, can someone suggest another solution?

Comment: Could you erase and reformat the drive containing the backups?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet. I was hoping to avoid totally erasing everything just in case I couldn't retrieve everything.

Comment: Try using `bypass` from the command line. See: [The root of the cause](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31679/how-can-i-delete-a-file-marked-as-backup-item).